# Is there any bumbers or snapinto view concept in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I am designing an application which shows 10 images with width and height 1400 x 800 in portrait mode with horizontal orientation. i have added the images in scrollviewer using stack panel. when i swipe or flick the images rolls in the view and stops in a position. 
if it stops in between the 6th and 7th image, and the 7th image is in the 75% view i want the 7th image to be moved to the left side of the screen.If the 6th image occupies the maximum view then the 7th image to be moved to the right side. I have seen this in image gallery of windows phone but the image moves only on left side. Android,html5 and ios have the option of snaping and bumber coccepts to acheve this. Is there any library to acheive in wp7. see the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `SlideView` in Teleriks RadControls library for Windows Phone (http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) has such snapping functionality.

Alternatively, you could look at the `LoopingSelector` in the toolkit (http://phone.codeplex.com/) and alter it so that it scrolls horizontally rather than vertically.